# How to replace Electron's IPC channel in a Web App

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, electron

I developed an Electron application few weeks ago with the framework AngularJS (used to make the client side). Today, I would like to convert this desktop application to a classic Web App.

The actual client-server communication is made with Electron's IPC channels. But it has to be replaced by something else. However, I don't really know what is the best way to replace them for the communication between my new Node.js server and the HTML pages (the same ones, always made with AngularJS).

I think there is a way to create new ipcMain and ipcRenderer modules to adapt them to the communication between a server and a client. But my skills in JavaScript are not good enought to do it. Does someone know how to make this adaptation, or maybe have a better idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty general question. I would use http://socket.io/

Comment: Hey ! Thank you for this information, this is perfect to replace the IPC channels behavior. I saw this JavaScript module during my researches but I didn't understand how it worked at first. So, thanks again for bring it to the discussion.